# How can I include an interactive CDF in a LaTeX document?

Tags: include, wolfram-mathematica

A CDF is an interative format of Mathematica 9. You must have 
[cdf-player](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) installed. How can I include an interactive CDF in a LaTeX document?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this is impossible. Maybe a good first step would be to ask on [the Matematica.SE site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) whether it's possible to embed CDF in PDF at all, and eventually what PDF instructions are needed. Once you know this, it should be possible to answer your question about doing it in PDFLaTeX. However, I'm quite dubious of this being possible at all :-/